# How to prevent lag in COD: IW PS4?

Tags: ps4, call-of-duty-infinite-warfare

My speed is 50mbps (download and upload). I don't know why but cod infinite warfare lags extremely. I can't even play with that much of lag.

When I shoot I don't get any hitmarkers.

I keep running and suddenly I teleport back. When I see the killcam, I look like an idiot because my character keeps staring into wall or sky(but I was actually running).

I play GTA online, Battlefield 1, Hardline and sometimes Uncharted 4 but I never experienced lag in any of them.

The problem is with me or with servers? Is my internet speed enough?

Is there anything I can do to prevent lag and enjoy the game?

Comment: Nope :) . I deal with the same problem daily. I have a 2MB download speed. Which is all I myself need to play on my own but my family makes it go down to 200kb. And your internet is only 50mb < megabits, not megabytes. There are 8 megabits in each megabyte. That means you have a 6.25 MB internet speed which is very good. I would suggest if you use a router to connect your console up to it with ethernet. But you shouldnt be lagging with that speed. Do you have family or are you using the internet on your own? Someone may be using it ;)

Comment: @ExperimentalRocket I can't connect it with ethernet because both are in different rooms. Does it make any difference connecting via ethernet? I'm the only one in the house. So there is no sharing.

Comment: Where is your router located? High up? And yes ethernet does make a difference. Yu can buy long ethernet cable, for this purpose.

Comment: @ExperimentalRocket The router is just outside the room maybe 10feet distance between ps4 and router. Thank you for your suggestion. I will try connecting via cable instead of wifi.

Answer (score 0):

If your router is far from your console you'll get packet loss which acts the same way lag does. Try using Ethernet cable or if the game allows you to, modify the amount of data received or the maximum ping for the game.

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is due to the interruption from your console being a distance from your router.

You can try connecting your console via ethernet. If you are not able to easily connect a cable from your console directly to your router then you can use a plug adaptor such as a TP-LINK connector that lets you plug one plug into a wall by our router and plug it in via ethernet, and then use the other plug by your console and connect that via another ethernet cable to your console, this will let you use the internet without relying on the wireless, and get a better speed because it will not get interrupted as easily. Personally, that is what I use for all my consoles and PCs.